# VBA Click on dynamic generated div with ID

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer-9

I have this situation that I'm struggling to solve without any luck. I use VBA in Excel to navigate to a website. On this website, I use VBA to click on a div with id `id-01`, which works fine. Clicking on that `div#id-01` will generate another div with id `id-02`, I want to click on this div. How can I click on the div with `id-02` with VBA?

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'
'code to navigate to site and wait for site to load
'

'Get div#id-01 and click on it
Set first = IE.document.getElementById("id-01")

'click it
first.click

'The following code does not work because
Set second = IE.document.getElementById("id-02")

second.click
```

Comment: Perhaps instead of element ID you could use [tag name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536439(v=vs.85).aspx)? Seems like this should be handled as "child" of id-01 instead of just clicking id-01 and then id-02

Comment: After the page is finished rendering and before I click on `div#id-01`, there is no `div#id-02`. I guess, it would make no different how you refer to `div#id-01` as child of `div#id-01` or target it will ID because the object `ID.document` is not updated about the existence of `div#id-02`, if the object knew about id-02, the above code should have worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820548/is-there-a-way-in-vba-to-get-elements-produced-by-javascript. The advice is to `Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,x)` between `first.click` and `Set second = ...` where `x` is some number of seconds.

Comment: @Robin, Thanks for pointing me to the resouce and No, it's is not the same case. The second div is generated on user interaction and not before the page has already finished loaded. The problem is different.

Comment: have you tried looping when ie.busy or not ready?

Comment: I had loop ... ie.busy and check the state to make sure the page is fully loaded. Yes

Answer (score 0):

I generally reset the document after the new element has been added by the first.

Try this:

```
   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    '
    'code to navigate to site and wait for site to load
    '
    set myDoc = IE.Document

    Set first = myDoc.getElementById("id-01")

    'click it
    first.click


    (WAIT 2 seconds)

    set myDoc = IE.Document

    Set second = IE.document.getElementById("id-02")

    second.click[/code]
```